# Android: Cannot show only text on overflow actionItem

Tags: android, android-actionbar, menuitem

I want to get an item to only show text on the optionsMenu in the action bar.
Here is my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<item
    android:id="@+id/select_recipients_return_to_compose"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"
       android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:title="Finish"/>

</menu>
```

Things I've tried:
1) True on onCreateOptionsMenu:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.create_broadcast_options_menu, menu);
    optionsMenu = menu;
    MenuItem menuItem = menu.getItem(0);

    menuItem.setEnabled(false);

    // check if our roles recipients are chcked and if
    Cursor cursor3 = getCheckedRecipients();

    // actually, just checked if they're ticked.
    if (cursor3 == null || cursor3.getCount() == 0) {
        menuItem.setVisible(false);
    } else {
        menuItem.setVisible(true);
        menuItem.setEnabled(true);
    }


    return true;
}
```

2) Setting the text manually

Anything else?

Right now it will show my home icon as the icon but will respond to clicks and behavior I set on onOptionsItemSelected().

Comment: If you want to force the item to the overflow, don't use `ifRoom`, use `never` instead.

Answer (score 1):

```
android:showAsAction="withText|always"
```

forces the menuItem to the be a action of your actionbar.

if you want it to be in the overflow use

```
android:showAsAction="withText|never"
```